# 4 columns in a row using Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to get 4 columns in a row.

**Code:**

```html
<div class="banner-static" style="margin-top: 30px; margin-bottom: 15px;">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="home-banner">
      <div class="col2 col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4">
        <p class="img3">
          <a href="#">
            <img class="top" src="/img/cms/banner1_hover.jpg" alt="" />
            <img class="bottom" src="/img/cms/banner1.jpg" alt="" />
          </a>
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col2 col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4">
        <p class="img3">
          <a href="#">
            <img class="top" src="/img/cms/banner2_hover.jpg" alt="" />
            <img class="bottom" src="/img/cms/banner2.jpg" alt="" />
          </a>
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col2 col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4">
        <p class="img3">
          <a href="#">
            <img class="top" src="/img/cms/banner3_hover.jpg" alt="" />
            <img class="bottom" src="/img/cms/banner3.jpg" alt="" />
          </a>
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col2 col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4">
        <p class="img3">
          <a href="#">
            <img class="top" src="/img/cms/banner3_hover.jpg" alt="" />
            <img class="bottom" src="/img/cms/banner3.jpg" alt="" />
          </a>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But i only get 3 columns, the last image jumps into to next row. Can somebody point me into the right direction ? 
Thanks

Comment: Add your CSS code please...

Comment: try this  col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-3

Comment: @Legionar It's Bootstrap, he doesn't need to.

Comment: Yes, thats why I added tag for it...

Answer (score 4):

Just apply the col-sm-3, col-md-3 class on columns instead of col-sm-4, col-md-4.

```
<div class="banner-static" style="margin-top: 30px; margin-bottom: 15px;">
<div class="row">
<div class="home-banner">
<div class="col2 col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
<p class="img3"><a href="#"><img class="top" src="/img/cms/banner1_hover.jpg"    alt="" /> <img class="bottom" src="/img/cms/banner1.jpg" alt="" /></a></p>
</div>
<div class="col2 col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
<p class="img3"><a href="#"><img class="top" src="/img/cms/banner2_hover.jpg"  alt="" /> <img class="bottom" src="/img/cms/banner2.jpg" alt="" /></a></p>
</div>
<div class="col2 col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
<p class="img3"><a href="#"><img class="top" src="/img/cms/banner3_hover.jpg" alt="" /> <img class="bottom" src="/img/cms/banner3.jpg" alt="" /></a></p>
</div>
<div class="col2 col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
<p class="img3"><a href="#"><img class="top" src="/img/cms/banner3_hover.jpg" alt="" /> <img class="bottom" src="/img/cms/banner3.jpg" alt="" /></a></p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Replace `col-sm-4` and `col-md-4` with `col-sm-3` and `col-md-3`. Twitter Bootstrap is a 12 column grid system and hence 4+4+4+4= 16 will push the last column to next row.

```html
<div class="banner-static" style="margin-top: 30px; margin-bottom: 15px;">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="home-banner">
      <div class="col2 col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
        <p class="img3">
          <a href="#">
            <img class="top" src="/img/cms/banner1_hover.jpg" alt="" />
            <img class="bottom" src="/img/cms/banner1.jpg" alt="" />
          </a>
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col2 col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
        <p class="img3">
          <a href="#">
            <img class="top" src="/img/cms/banner2_hover.jpg" alt="" />
            <img class="bottom" src="/img/cms/banner2.jpg" alt="" />
          </a>
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col2 col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
        <p class="img3">
          <a href="#">
            <img class="top" src="/img/cms/banner3_hover.jpg" alt="" />
            <img class="bottom" src="/img/cms/banner3.jpg" alt="" />
          </a>
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col2 col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
        <p class="img3">
          <a href="#">
            <img class="top" src="/img/cms/banner3_hover.jpg" alt="" />
            <img class="bottom" src="/img/cms/banner3.jpg" alt="" />
          </a>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<div class="col2 col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
<p class="img3"><a href="#"><img class="top" src="/img/cms/banner1_hover.jpg"    alt="" /> <img class="bottom" src="/img/cms/banner1.jpg" alt="" /></a></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Care to explain what you've changed?

Answer (score 0):

The Bootstrap grid is split up into 12 columns. Divide 12 by the number of columns you want, and you will get the number for that class.

For example, 12 divided by 4, is 3. So your classes should be col-sm-3 and col-md-3.

https://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/

Comment: Why has this been downvoted? It's given a fair amount more info than other answers.. I don't understand.

Comment: Not sure why it was down voted. But yeah, once again the trollers.